# WPF Listview - Get row where property changed

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a listview with objects that have int IDs and string names. The name column is a textbox that is editable by the user. If the user changes a name, I want to be able to search the list for other objects with that same ID and change those names as well.

My big question is, I want to use the LostFocus property of the textbox to get the entire row, or object, instead of just the textbox.

The XAML below is greatly simplified, but I think it gets the basic idea across:

```
<ListView x:Name="linkList"
<GridViewColumn Width="75">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding linkName}" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"/>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>

<GridViewColumn Width="75">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding linkID}"/>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

So in code behind:

```
    private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //sender is the textbox in this case. so how 
        //would I get the object in that particular row so I can get its ID#?
    }
```

I need to identify that particular row since the user can either click on a different row or press "enter" to save the name change. So going by the currently selected row is no good. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Google for the `GetVisualAncestor<T>` extension and use that.

```
((TextBox)sender).GetVisualAncestor<ListViewItem>();
```

Comment: There is no GetVisualAncestor method for Textbox.

Comment: @Akansha do you know how to read? I said Google for the extension method. LMAO. Down vote for your lack of reading skills? Are you 5?

Comment: I down voted your answer because it does not solve the issue rather it throws another error. If you are not sure about the answer and want to suggest something you can just add a comment to the question asked. If you are providing a suggestion atleast leave a link of some tutorial. Suggesting someone to google for the issue is no where an answer, and on top of that you want me upvote it. ha ha..  If the user have to go through the trouble of googling then what is the point of posting a question here. Ya am 5.. Atleast I am older to you. :p

Comment: @SledgeHammer That was a good place to start, I wasn't even sure terms I was looking for to even google it.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty obvious now, but I just had to find the ancestor of the type of ListViewItem and I'm able to pull the info I need from that object.

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem changedRow = GetAncestorOfType<ListViewItem>(sender as TextBox);
    //now I can get the info I need from the changedRow object!
}

public T GetAncestorOfType<T>(FrameworkElement child) where T : FrameworkElement
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    if (parent != null && !(parent is T))
        return (T)GetAncestorOfType<T>((FrameworkElement)parent);
    return (T)parent;
}
```